# Rewrite rule to prettify two $_GET variables while in a new endpoint from a page

Tags: wp-query, permalinks, rewrite-rules, regex, query-variable

I'm trying to create a permalink rule which is a few levels deep.

I have a basic page `/page-slug/` - I'm appending to it a new endpoint: `/page-slug/my-endpoint/` - from here I need to nest one id and one string that contain `$_GET` variables, such as `/page-slug/my-endpoint/?some_id=123&some_string=string` which should become: `/page-slug/my-endpoint/123/string/`

I got all the query vars successfully registered and I can grab them for use in my methods (e.g if I do `var_dump( $wp_query->query_vars )` they will show up where set via `$_GET`).

What I can't get to work is the rewrite rule to turn a URL in a pretty permalink (this snippet is run at `init` hook time):

```
    foreach ( $this->query_vars as $key => $var ) {

        add_rewrite_endpoint( $var, EP_PERMALINK | EP_PAGES, $var );

        if ( 'my-endpoint' == $key ) {

            add_rewrite_tag( '%some_id%',   '([^&]+)' );
            add_rewrite_tag( '%some_string%', '([^&]+)' );

            $page_id   = get_some_page_id(); 
            $page_slug = get_post( $page_id )->post_name;

            // e.g. /page-slug/my-endpoint/123/some-string/
            add_rewrite_rule(
                "{$page_slug}/{$var}/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$",
                'index.php?page_id=' . $page_id . '&some_id=$matches[1]&some_string=$matches[2]',
                'top'
            );

        }
    }
```

I tested the regex and does not look wrong, it catches what I need (`123`  and `some-string`).

Up to `'page-slug/'` and also `'page-slug/my-query-var/` (2 levels deep) it works just fine, it's the two rewrite tags that don't work when used in a pretty permalink structure.

I tried with https://wordpress.org/plugins/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer/ and the rules show up there - but I'm not sure about their interpretation

Comment: so your rewrite rules are all working? it's not clear what you're having a problem with.

Comment: partially, query vars are working, rewrite rules for the part after the endpoint are not - if I head over `/page-slug/my-endpoint/123/some-string` and check for `isset( $wp_query->query_vars['some_id'] )` it returns false (but no 404), if I do the same with `/page-slug/my-endpoint/?some_id=123&some_string=some-string` it returns true

Comment: I'm assuming the missing `%` in the 2nd `add_rewrite_tag` is a typo here? I can't test your code exactly, since parts are missing, but if I hardcode a page slug and endpoint name in the rewrite rule, it works for me.

Comment: yes it was, sorry I deleted it while editing the snippet for stackoverflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are using endpoints incorrectly. When a endopoint is created, a new rewrite rule is created using a query var with the same name of the endpoint; its value is taken from the string that follows the endpoint definition. So, if you register "my-endpoint" and build this URL:

```
/page-slug/my-endpoint/123/some-string
```

The endpoint is passed as `my-endpoint=123/some-string`.

As far I understand from your code, you don't need the `my-endpoint` query var, so you don't need to register it; or you can register it with `false` value for query var argument (this argument is not currently documented in [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint) but exists in [source code](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_endpoint/#source-code)):

```
add_rewrite_endpoint( $var, EP_PERMALINK | EP_PAGES, false );
```

Or, if you want the endpoint only in pages:

```
add_rewrite_endpoint( $var, EP_PAGES, false );
```

Also, you check `'my-endpoint' == $key` buth then include `$var` as endpoint name and as part in the URL, not `$key`.

Without knowing what `$this->query_vars` and `get_some_page_id()` are, I can not test your code exactly but this should work:

```
foreach ( $this->query_vars as $key => $var ) {

    if ( 'my-endpoint' == $key ) {

        add_rewrite_tag( '%some_id%',   '([^&]+)' );
        add_rewrite_tag( '%some_string%', '([^&]+)' );

        $page_id   = get_some_page_id(); 
        $page_slug = get_post( $page_id )->post_name;

        // e.g. /page-slug/my-endpoint/123/some-string/
        // $key is equal to my-endpoint here because of the previous check
        add_rewrite_rule(
            "^{$page_slug}/{$key}/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$",
            'index.php?page_id=' . $page_id . '&some_id=$matches[1]&some_string=$matches[2]',
            'top'
        );

    }
}
```

**Note**: Do not forget to flush rewrite rules before testing this code.

Comment: thanks cybmeta while you were answering I also found a solution - not only I had to write `add_rewrite_endpoint( 'my-endpoint', EP_PAGES, false );` but in my case the `false` arg was very important - there is a third  parameter in add_rewrite_endpoint and that tells whether adding a query var for the endpoint or not in my case I didn't need it and it was messing up with the rest of the url with the rewrite rule (passing the rest of the url as query var value) - please edit your answer

Comment: I see that third parameter in the [source code of `add_rewrite_endpoint()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_endpoint/#source-code) but it is not documented in the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint). I didn't know about it.

Comment: Answer edited ;)